# Black screen after waking up from suspend (Redmibook pro)

Tags: 20.04, suspend, screen, 23.04

- On wake up after being suspended my laptop I am presented with black
  screen. System works properly after waking up (I can press volume
  button and hear sound, I can log in, I can open terminal and write
  commands). But to do this I have to use a flashlight pointed on the
  screen to light up pixels. So IPS matrix is reciving correct picture but
  does not light up pixels.
- If I boot system after poweroff I will see normal screen.
- If suspend system with normal screen and than wake it up I will see black screen
- If I reboot system with black screen holding F2 I will see BIOS with black screen

---

- Model: Redmibook Pro 15 2022 16Gb
- i7-12650H alder lake
- Nvidia RTX 2050
- Ubuntu 23.04

---

What I have tried:

- swap graphics between nvidia and intel
- edit /etc/default/grub
- ubuntu 20.04 (same story)
- Ctrl + Alt + F3 then Ctrl + Alt + F2
- Purge everything from nvidia
- Windows 11 wakes up normally
- Randomly disable something from `sudo cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled`

Same system (Ubuntu 23.04 and 20.04) running on another laptop does not show black screen afrer suspention